# Python Monty hall n number of doors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a model of the Monty Hall program running but I need to figure out how to ask the user for the number of doors of in this case, hiding places. The code for the simulation works, it's just the starting section I need help with. This is what I have so far, thanks for any help in advance.

```
import random

#Ask the user for how many runs to simumlate

runs = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate?"))
switchwins, nonswitchwins, switchlosses, nonswitchlosses = 0, 0, 0, 0

# Get the random number started with a seed
random.seed()

#run once for user switching and once for user not switching
for swap in True,False:
# Do everything for the number of runs we have
for i in range(runs):
    #Ask the user for the number of hiding places which must be greater than 3
    while True:
        hidingplaces = int(input("This game requires 3 or more hiding places. How many would you like?"))
        if hidingplaces < 3:
        #return error 
            raise ValueError(f'doors must be greater than three, not {hidingplaces}')
        else: 
            break

    # All prizes are nothing apart from one which holds the coin
    prizes = ['nothing', 'nothing', 'coin']
    # Randomly mix them up
    random.shuffle(prizes)

    #select a random location
    ChoiceA = random.randrange(hidingplaces)

    # print("Before the prize is revealed, I will show you what is in one of the other hiding places")

    # remove one of the other hiding places which has nothing as a prize and isn't ChoiceA
    for currentlocation, contents in enumerate(prizes):
        if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents == "nothing":
            showlocation = currentlocation
            # print("There is nothing in this location", showlocation)
            break


    if swap:
        #swap to the other location
        for currentlocation, contents in enumerate(prizes):
            if currentlocation != ChoiceA and currentlocation != showlocation:
                swap_to = currentlocation

        # check if the swapped choice is a win
        if prizes[swap_to] == "coin":
            switchwins +=1
        else: 
            switchlosses +=1
    # when not swapping locations check for win
    else:
        if prizes[ChoiceA] == "coin":
            nonswitchwins +=1
        else: 
            nonswitchlosses +=1

 print("This is the number of wins if the user switched", round((switchwins/runs)*100,1), "%")

 print("This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch", round((nonswitchwins/runs)*100,1),"%")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e7e700a3b515> in <module>()
     57         # when not swapping locations check for win
     58         else:
---> 59             if prizes[ChoiceA] == "coin":
     60                 nonswitchwins +=1
     61             else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Your code runs and behaves fine to me.

Comment: Posted the whole code now :)

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting as well, and/or the expected behavior vs. the actual behavior? I.e., what exactly is going wrong, and where, and what should it be doing instead?

Comment: Edited the error message in

Comment: I fixed your second issue. Check my answer. If it fixed it, don't forget to click the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're reporting is not, after all, with the user input routine. It is that you are allowing the user to specify `hidingplaces` > 3 while at the same time  hardcoding the list `prizes` to have exactly 3 entries. `ChoiceA`, which can be (randomly) set to any number less than `hidingplaces`, is used as an index into `prizes`.  It raises the exception you report whenever `ChoiceA` happens to be greater than 2.

Strategies to fix this might include (a) making use of the value of `hidingplaces` when you define the list of `prizes` or (b) using `ChoiceA % len(prizes)` as the index into `prizes` instead of just `ChoiceA`.  Note that these have different effects on the statistical behavior of the simulation: the correct choice depends on how you want it to behave.  From the comment next to your existing definition of `prizes`, this definition is *probably* what you intend:

```
prizes = [ 'coin' ] + [ 'nothing' ] * ( hidingplaces - 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code. I rewrote it and simplified it, fixed some syntax errors, and fixed some indent errors.

Check the comments in the code.

**EDIT:** I have fixed the code.

```
def askDoors():
    '''
    Ask the user for the number of hiding places which must be greater than 3
    '''
    return int(input("This game requires 3 or more hiding places. How many would you like?"))

hidingplaces = askDoors()

while hidingplaces < 3:
    # return error
    print('Doors must be greater than three, not %d.' % hidingplaces)
    hidingplaces = askDoors()

print('Start.') # put game here (recommended to use a function)
```

**EDIT:** For the second problem, just change prizes to `prizes = ['coin']` and add this right after it.

```
for i in range(hidingplaces):
   prizes.append('nothing')
```

Comment: Tried your code (thank you!) but it returned an error, if edited mine slightly but it keeps coming up with the error "list index out of range"

Comment: @Billygem08 Put my code in a separate file, and run it. It should work. The "list index out of range' error might be in the other code.

Comment: you are using `hidingplaces` as a global and as a local variable. and your function `askDoors()` is not returning anything. that's not a good practice... and also not answering the question...

Comment: The second issue has been fixed.